# unable to check if string is substring of another in python

Tags: python, string

I'm a beginner in python and I have 2 string variables called

```
user_comment = "Hobbit 2013:Bad Movie"
comment_in_movie = "Hobbit 2013 user@gmail.com:Bad Movie"
```

I am trying to check if the user_comment is inside the second variable using :

```
if user_comment in comment_in_movie:
     print("found")
```

In more detail I am trying to check if all the above words exist in the second string .
But I get no result . I think the problem is that the user string does not appear in the same way in the second string since there are more words between `"2013"` and `":Bad Movie"`
I would appreciate your help in guiding me to solve this simple task .
Thank you in advance .

Comment: Please describe what exactly should be considered a match!

Comment: `in` check if the entirety of string 1 is in string 2. in your case there is SOME overlap, but clearly user_comment contains parts not in comment_in_movie. what are you trying to achieve? if there is always going to be a colon you can always slice the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed correct on your assumption. The strings will only get matched if the **exact** string is found. You may do something like so:

```py
user_comment = "Hobbit 2013:Bad Movie"
comment_in_movie = "Hobbit 2013 user@gmail.com:Bad Movie"

for string in user_comment.split(":"):
    if string in comment_in_movie:
        print(f"Found '{string}' in comment_in_movie.")
```

Which will output:

```
Found 'Hobbit 2013' in comment_in_movie.
Found 'Bad Movie' in comment_in_movie.
```

If you are trying to check for individual words, you can replace the `:` delimiter with   and split the string by  :

```py
user_comment = "Hobbit 2013:Bad Movie"
comment_in_movie = "Hobbit 2013 user@gmail.com:Bad Movie"

for string in user_comment.replace(":", " ").split(" "):
    if string in comment_in_movie:
        print(f"Found '{string}' in comment_in_movie.")
```

Will output:

```
Found 'Hobbit' in comment_in_movie.
Found '2013' in comment_in_movie.
Found 'Bad' in comment_in_movie.
Found 'Movie' in comment_in_movie.
```

You may also use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to return to you a single `True` or `False` that will tell you if all strings are present. This can be done in one line like so:

```py
user_comment = "Hobbit 2013:Bad Movie"
comment_in_movie = "Hobbit 2013 user@gmail.com:Bad Movie"

in_str = all(x in comment_in_movie for x in user_comment.replace(":", " ").split(" "))
print(in_str)
```

The above will output `True`. You will notice that if you change `user_comment` to say `Dark Knight` in the movie name section you will get `False` as the output.

Comment: This is making a big specific assumption that the colon is key. The next check will almost certainly fail, as it won't contain a :. Better to replace all punctuation characters in both strings with space, before testing –

Comment: `str.replace(old, new)` does not throw error if the given `old` is not in the `str`. While, yes, there was an assumption that `:` would be there, its lack thereof won't necessarily be an issue. OP should be able to generalize as he/she sees fit.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, user_comment is not in comment_in_movie, you need to split user_comment by space then search for each word. Here is the solution:

```
  if all(x in comment_in_movie for x in user_comment.split(" ")):
    print ("found")
```

Answer (score 1):

You answered is right by your own.Now you can solve this problem by many steps:

1. Store the string as a list with elements of that list equal to the words separated by spaces in the string and use a loop to check whether the elements of first string are present in the second string.But the problem with this method is that it is return true even if the elements of the first string are present in the second string even in the wrong order...Hope you got the answer.If you don't know about loops you can learn them from no. of tutorials present om different platforms or just text back.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your

```
user_comment ="Hobbit 2013:Bad Movie"
```

Into two separate strings by using

```
user_comment = "Hobbit 2013:Bad Movie"
comment_in_movie = "Hobbit 2013 user@gmail.com:Bad Movie"
split_string = user_comment.split(":")
if split_string[0] in comment_in_movie and split_string[1] in comment_in_movie:
    print("found")
```

and then compare them to the:

```
comment_in_movie = "Hobbit 2013 user@gmail.com:Bad Movie"
```

Notice how this answer is different from the first one because you access the split text by list index.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, in order to test whether `comment_in_movie` contains **all characters** from `user_comment` **in the correct order**. Additional characters that are missing from `user_comment` are permitted anywhere inside `comment_in_movie`, and the loop over the characters of `comment_in_movie` will just carry on until it finds matching characters again. Provided that the end of `user_comment` is reached before running out of characters in `comment_in_movie`, that is considered a match.

```
user_comment = "Hobbit 2013:Bad Movie"
comment_in_movie = "Hobbit 2013 user@gmail.com:Bad Movie"

i = 0

for c in comment_in_movie:
    if user_comment[i] != c:
        continue
    i += 1
    if i == len(user_comment):
        found = True
        break
else:
    found = False

if found:
    print("found")
```

The above code makes no assumptions whatsoever regarding permitted places in which missing characters may occur.  In some sense, this is more flexible because it checks that all characters are present, while not needing any advance knowledge of what delimiter(s) to use to split the string.  However, it might be for example that gaps in the middle of a word should not be acceptable (e.g. if `user_comment` contained `Hit` instead of `Hobbit`).

For this reason, an alternative version is given below which is based on looking for **whole words**.  All the words in `user_comment` now have to appear in `comment_in_movie`, again **in the correct order**, and non-word characters e.g. punctuation are simply ignored.  The logic is exactly the same, except that we loop over words in lists, instead of characters in strings.  So for example, `"Hobbit 2013,Bad Movie"` would be "found", without requiring that the comma is contained in `comment_in_movie`, but `"Hit 2013:Bad Movie"` would not be "found".

```
import re

user_comment = "Hobbit 2013:Bad Movie"
comment_in_movie = "Hobbit 2013 user@gmail.com:Bad Movie"

user_comment_words = re.findall("\w+", user_comment)
comment_in_movie_words = re.findall("\w+", comment_in_movie)

i = 0
for w in comment_in_movie_words:
    if user_comment_words[i] != w:
        continue
    i += 1
    if i == len(user_comment_words):
        found = True
        break
else:
    found = False

if found:
    print("found")
```